# ggplot not respecting xlimits in coord_cartesian

Tags: r, ggplot2

A new problem with the same code from an earlier question. Funny because this is the first line of code in my R journey that just keeps stumping me. Following up on the previous post, now the extra line charts are being plotted but I realized that the x axis is not respecting the limits I'm trying to set. Here is the code. Changing the values for `xlim` does not 'zoom in' on the x axis and seems to have no effect at all:

```
ggplot(aes(x = age, y = friend_count), data = pf) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(13,90)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.05,
             position = position_jitter(h = 0),
             color = 'orange') +
  coord_trans(y = "sqrt") +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun = mean) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = .1),
            linetype = 2, color = 'blue') +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = .9),
            linetype = 2, color = 'blue')
```

Comment: You can only use one `coord_*` per plot, so the 2nd one is overriding the first one.

Comment: Thanks. I just found that that was the culprit and was coming back to post. Nothing to be done about it then I guess.

Comment: Use `coord_trans(y = "sqrt", xlim = c(13,90))` if you want to set x limits and use a transformation on y.